# How does azure load balancer probe work for Worker Roles?

Tags: azure, load-balancing, azure-worker-roles

I'm a little confused from the descriptions I've read and have a bunch of FAQs. 
So here goes.

If you have no input endpoints defined, then there is no load balancing required - duh.

If you have input endpoint port 80 defined for worker roles, will azure automatically probe that as HTTP to determine which roles are 'up', or is that something that only happens for Web Roles? (It happens for web roles right?)

If you have no HTTP endpoints and only TCP endpoints, does azure pick a TCP endpoint to probe, or does it just do the default probing thing where it doesn't ping your endpoint at all?